# I still don't get why Misfits-Simon wanted to travel back in time in the first place

Tags: time-travel, misfits

So future-Simon goes back in time and becomes the superhoodie in order to save the gang and to make Alicia fall in love with present-Simon.

But I don't get it. Why on earth would the very first future-Simon travel back in time? Because that Simon didn't have a future-Simon to make Alicia fall in love with him? So Simon would still be kinda shy and not superhoodie, so it does not make sense that he should start the loop.

I know it's a loop with no beginning and end, but still - it's quite unsatisfying to think that "poof" - suddenly you have a future-Simon who already has experienced love with Alicia to start the loop. Please help :)

Comment: Possibly related http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4966/how-do-the-timelines-from-misfits-align

Comment: Please check the answers in provided link. Short story: there must be a continuity when Simon and Alisha fall in love "naturally" (without help of future-Simon) and go to Las Vegas (we could see the picture). After her death (maybe killed by Big Cheese?) Simon came back in time as a Super Hoodie to save Alisha/inspire her to fall in love with present-Simon.